# How to save GtkTerm output to file automatically

Tags: linux

I need to capture logs from `GtkTerm` tool directly to text file.
I tried

```
gtkterm > /path/to/file/file.txt
```

and

```
touch /path/to/file/file.txt
gtkterm -f /path/to/file/file.txt
```

in both cases `GtkTerm` shell started to generate log but target file was empty

Please provide solution

*Advanced: how to start `GtkTerm` with already saved configuration and save log to file

Comment: Not an answer, but I had a similar issue, and resolved using the command line, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer

Answer (score 1):

Current `gtkterm` has a built-in logging facility in its Log Menu, "To file...". Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to have this logging turned on automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding -e switch to the command:

from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gtkterm.1.html manual:

> ```
> -e, --echo
>           Set local echo.
> ```

Comment: Local echo means that the terminal window itself echoes any character entered. I tried using -e with logging, and this is not a solution. Or please provide the entire command to be used.